# Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Java Spring Boot app which works with a Postgres database. I want to use Docker for both of them. I initially put just the Postgres in Docker, and I had a `docker-compose.yml` file defined like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
        container_name: sample_db
        image: postgres:9.5
        volumes:
            - sample_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sample
            - POSTGRES_USER=sample
            - POSTGRES_DB=sample
            - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        ports:
            - 5432:5432

volumes:
    sample_db: {}
```

Then, when I issued the commands `sudo dockerd` and `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`, it was starting the database. I could connect using `pgAdmin` for example, by using `localhost` as server and port `5432`. Then, in my Spring Boot app, inside the `application.properties` file I defined the following properties.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample
spring.datasource.username=sample
spring.datasource.password=sample
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

At this point I could run my Spring Boot app locally through Spring Suite, and it all was working fine. Then, I wanted to also add my Spring Boot app as Docker image. I first of all created a Dockerfile in my project directory, which looks like this:

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/manager.jar manager.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","manager.jar"]
```

Then, I entered to the directory of the project issued `mvn clean` followed by `mvn install`. Next, issued `docker build -f Dockerfile -t manager .` followed by `docker tag 9c6b1e3f1d5e myuser/manager:latest` (the id is correct). Finally, I edited my existing `docker-compose.yml` file to look like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
      image: myuser/manager:latest
      ports: 
          - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
          - db
    db:
        container_name: sample_db
        image: postgres:9.5
        volumes:
            - sample_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sample
            - POSTGRES_USER=sample
            - POSTGRES_DB=sample
            - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        ports:
            - 5432:5432

volumes:
    sample_db: {}
```

But, now if I issue `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` command, the database again starts correctly, but I get errors and exit code 1 for the web app part. The problem is the connection string. I believe I have to change it to something else, but I don't know what it should be. I get the following error messages:

```
web_1  | 2017-06-27 22:11:54.418 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
web_1  | 
web_1  | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I create a demo project which use Spring Boot 2 + Docker Compose and Postgresql, https://muzir.github.io/spring/docker/docker-compose/postgres/2019/03/24/Spring-Boot-Docker.html

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Each container has its own network interface with its own localhost. So change how Java points to Postgres:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample
```

To:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sample
```

`db` will resolve to the proper Postgres IP.

---

Bonus. With docker-compose you don't need to build your image by hand. So change:

```
web:
  image: myuser/manager:latest
```

To:

```
web:
  build: .
```

Comment: one thing I don't understand is, I'm using JPA in my application and in order to build the spring-boot app it needs to connect to my DB, which I cannot do if my postgre docker isn't running, correct? So basically with the similar application properties configured to connect to dockerized postgre db I can't build my app in first place...

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and I lost some time to understand and solve this problem:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I show all the properties so that everyone understands.
`application.properties:`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

`docker-compose.yml:`

```
  version: "3"
  services:
    springapp:
      build: .
      container_name: springapp
      environment:
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/testdb
      ports:
        - 8000:8080
      restart: always
      depends_on:
        - db
    db:
      image: postgres
      container_name: db
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - POSTGRES_DB=testdb
        - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      ports:
        - 5000:5432
      volumes:
        - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      restart: always
  volumes:
    pgdata:
```

For start spring application with local database we use url localhost.
For connect to container with database we need change 'localhost' on your database service, in my case '**localhost**' to '**db**'.
*Solution*: add `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment in `docker-compose.yml` wich rewrite `spring.datasource.url` value for connect:

```
  environment:
    SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/testdb
```

I hope this helps someone save his time.

Comment: can you share your dockerfile

Comment: I didn`t know that env variables override what`s in the app.properties. Thanks Alexander!

Comment: Thaank you, it took me some hours to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
version: "2"
services:
    sample_db-postgresql:
        image: postgres:9.5
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sample
            - POSTGRES_USER=sample
            - POSTGRES_DB=sample
         volumes:
            - sample_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
    sample_db:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ENV variable to change the db address in your docker-compose.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ENV POSTGRES localhost
ADD /target/manager.jar manager.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar manager.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://$POSTGRES:5432/sample
```

docker-compose:
`

```
  container_name: springapp
  environment:
   - POSTGRES=db`
```