# Java app in docker: Failed to get driver instance for postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, docker

I created a java web app. When I run java -jar xxx.jar on host, it can connect to Postgres DB on my host without any issue. But my app can not get driver instance for the same jdbc URL when it runs in a docker container I created. The error is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for 
>   jdbcUrl=’jdbc:postgresql://ip_of_my_host:5432/srr’

This is how I run docker image:

```sh
docker run -p 4567:4567 \
  -e JP_RESULTS_DB_URL=’jdbc:postgresql://ip_of_my_host:5432/srr’ \
  -e JP_RESULTS_DB_USERNAME=my_username \
  -e JP_RESULTS_DB_PASSWORD=my_password \
  -it id_of_image
```

4567 is the port number of my Rest API server. Do I need to also set porting for 5432? If I add "-p 5432:5432", I got error it is already allocated so I didn't add this port to docker run.

What could be the problem? Is it the driver issue or port issue or something else?

I haven't found any useful answers here yet so I have to ask.

Comment: `’` <- Wrong quote characters perhaps?

Comment: What host are you using for Postgres? Is it public or on your local?

Comment: This problem was solved by changing back single quote. Google doc automatically changed my single quote to tilt and I didn’t notice until @Phil pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You should use docker-compose to build up the stack and then mount the postgresql driver,java etc to build up the whole infrastructure.

for that you need to create docker-compose yml.

for e.g. find the below link

[Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790923/docker-compose-spring-boot-postgres-connection)

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by changing back single quote. Google doc automatically changed my single quote to tilt and I didn’t notice until @Phil pointed out.