# Docker HikariPool-1 exception - driver doesnt recieve packets from the server

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I got this exception and can't resolve it. It works in intellij, so I thought that everything is correct, but then I try to use it in docker and this happens. I'd be glad if u guys helped me. Couldn't find any solution that would fit me while searching the internet.The error is longer, but StackOverflow doesnt allow me to add so much code to such a short comment.

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.4)

2022-04-08 00:24:44.230  INFO 7 --- [           main] p.k.s.SpringDataLessonApplication        : Starting SpringDataLessonApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.14.1 on e9b077a5d5df with PID 7 (/spring-data-lesson-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /)
2022-04-08 00:24:44.233  INFO 7 --- [           main] p.k.s.SpringDataLessonApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-04-08 00:24:44.612  INFO 7 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-04-08 00:24:44.651  INFO 7 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 31 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-04-08 00:24:44.984  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-04-08 00:24:45.023  INFO 7 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
2022-04-08 00:24:45.153  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-04-08 00:24:45.243  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-04-08 00:24:46.337 ERROR 7 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:242) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
        

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:949) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:819) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        ... 59 common frames omitted

2022-04-08 00:24:46.339  WARN 7 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:242) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/:5.6.5.Final]
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD target/spring-data-lesson-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD java -jar spring-data-lesson-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My app.properties

```
#data base
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: You have the Spring database URL set to point back to the application container on a different port.  You also might look at [Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790923/docker-compose-spring-boot-postgres-connection) for a different recipe, if the database is running inside a container as well.