# Can't access application run on Docker from outside like Postman

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have created a Spring Boot project connected to PostgreSQL.
When running the project and connecting from my IDE, the PostgreSQL I installed within Docker is working fine.

I use Docker Desktop version 4.6.1 on Windows 11, and I have faced two problems when starting docker.

First:

```
docker run --name myapp --network=host -d 220d023bd426
```

For the command above, the application is starting, but I can't access it from the outside like Postman, then I try

```
docker exec -it 099583cc05b6 /bin/bash
```

and use curl to test it works.

Second:

```
docker run --name myapp -p 8181:8080 -d 220d023bd426
```

**For command above, it shows an error:**

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:6543 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP

Comment: please show exact `curl` commands that succeed, what are images `220d023bd426` and `099583cc05b6`

Comment: This one 220d023bd426 a image and 099583cc05b6  a container id

Comment: The CURL that I test on container:

`curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8181/emp?empNo=102298' \
--header 'emp;' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "percentage_range": 86
}'`

Comment: How are you starting the database?  How are you configuring the connection to it?  In Docker `localhost` usually means "the current container"; you might look at other questions like [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname) for some ideas on standard Docker networking.

Comment: @DavidMaze the database I install as a docker, I use application.properties for connecting to the database, `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:6543/demo`
if I run on IntelliJ, it's working fine. the problem when I run as a docker show connection confused with the second command. Note both the database and application I run as the Docker.

Comment: That is trying to connect to port 6543 in your Spring application container.  The database is in a different container, which is not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.  [Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790923/docker-compose-spring-boot-postgres-connection) has another example.

Comment: @DavidMaze I follow sample docker-compose it works, but I still can't test from Postman using IP 172.26.0.3 and 127.0.0.1

docker inspect
 `"IPAddress": "",
"IPPrefixLen": 0,
"IPv6Gateway": "",
"MacAddress": "",
"Networks": {
    "spring-boot-data_default": {
        "Aliases": [
            "springapp",
            "40136a92fc9d"
        ],
        "Gateway": "172.26.0.1",
        "IPAddress": "172.26.0.3",`

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address doesn't work in a wide variety of situations, and it's never necessary to look it up.  From a browser or a tool like Postman you should usually be able to connect to `localhost` (or the host's IP address or DNS name) and the first published `ports:` number.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze now I can test from Postman.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `--network=host` to the second command as well, otherwise it is trying to connect to the 127.0.0.1 of the container.
But please make sure you understand what [network=host](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) means

Comment: Host networking doesn't work on Windows or MacOS.  If it works, it disables Docker's networking stack, which you usually don't want (there's a suggestion that they've remapped their database port, for example, which isn't an option with host networking).