# docker image throwing error while running springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, containers

I have created one project in `springboot` in which I have used database as `mysql`. API is running `properly`.later I created docker image using jar file.

[image]

I tried to run container using below command.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 eazybytes/accounts
```

it is throwing the below error.

[image]

Error is related with database.
below was my `application.properties`

```
server.port=8080

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Ddixit90@

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

what mistake I am doing?

Comment: "*`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/testdb`*" - This cannot work. In the container, `localhost` resolves to the container itself, and in the container, on port `3307`, there is no database running.

Comment: You are trying to connect to the containers localhost, which has no db running. Take a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44790923/1563297

Comment: You will need to run the containers on the same network. You can create a network with `docker network create testnetwork`. Then when you run the containers you can use the `--network testnetwork` option. You  also might want to use the `--hostname` option when running the MySQL container to set the hostname within the network. Then in your code, you can just use `jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/testdb`

Answer (score 0):

Ok since, I'm not familiar with coding and wanted to test in real condition your problem, I created a simple java springboot application to access a database with mysql.

I've tried before this, to deploy a lot of project linked to your docker image but in vain. so this is what i have done:

First I have deployed my database according to your configurations:

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'testdb'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'Ddixit90@'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3307:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
# Names our volume
volumes:
  my-db:
```

I deployed the container with this command:

```
❯ docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container springboot-dockerfile-db-1  Started
```

checked if my container was successfully deployed:

```
❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS          PORTS
                NAMES
fb8e471c1091   mysql:5.7                            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago   Up 26 seconds   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   springboot-dockerfile-db-1
```

Tested my database connection:

```
❯ mysql --host=localhost --port=3307 --user=root --password=Ddixit90@ testdb
WARNING: Forcing protocol to  TCP  due to option specification. Please explicitly state intended protocol.
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 5.7.37 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [testdb]>
```

succesful.

For the java app, I have followed the steps here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ to create my java app

I have spend most of the time on the configuration of the pom.xml lol
here was my application.properties after all my problems fixed:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
# logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
# logging.level.com.howtodoinjava=DEBUG
# spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

I built my jar and run the app locally along with the database:

```
mvn clean install && java -jar target/accessingdatamysql.jar
```

Cool, i could access to the localhost:8080/demo/all, post the data with curl, according to the above tutorial, and here is the result of:

Then, to containerize my java app here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3-openjdk-17-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Add the application's jar to the container
COPY ./target/accessingdatamysql.jar .
 
#execute the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","accessingdatamysql.jar"]
```

I tested to run it manually:

```
❯ docker build --no-cache -t test-java-mysql -f Dockerfile .

❯ docker run -d test-java-mysql -p 8080:8080
9c1687803f1026437de142aab3acc95f1cb1a64aafb8b10f83af1544732c8ee7
❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                               NAMES
9c1687803f10   test-java-mysql                      "java -jar accessing…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds                                       charming_shockley
```

as expected, in the java logs:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Now that we are at the same point, lets fix this.

This time, i decided to use spring environment variables instead of static values in my application.properties, this way if you want to modify something you just have to change the environment variables instead of rebuilding entierly the jar. so here is my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I rebuild the jar with:

```
mvn clean install
```

I chose to use docker-compose to launch both mysql db and java app.
After a long serie of testing, here is the final docker-compose that work perfectly, since db and javaapp are in the same network with custom db hostname (mysql):

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    hostname: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      # Database used by the java app
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db_example'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'springuser'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'ThePassword'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'Ddixit90@'
    ports:
      #map port 3306 of the container to the port 3307 of the host (to test and check with dbeaver or mysql client (optional))
      - '3307:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted: all finaly worked with this:
    volumes:
      - /tmp/mysql-container:/var/lib/mysql
  javaapp:
    build: .
    container_name: java-mysql
    environment:
      # spring datasources variables since they are not in application.properties
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/db_example"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: "springuser"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: "ThePassword"
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
    - db
```

To run the containers:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Testing the java app persistence, according to the above tutorial:

```
❯ curl localhost:8080/demo/add -d name=First -d email=someemail@someemailprovider.com
Saved
```

here is the result:

[image]

here is the java code if you want to check in details:

> https://github.com/bimguess/so-71983590

If someone have any question, Im here to help. bguess