# Problem in communication of docker mySQL container and my spring boot application container

Tags: spring-boot, docker

When i start application in IDE, it works correctly, but when i use docker-compose for starting my project, something goes wrong and my application container restarts, i have shared my project on github https://github.com/MatveyAndrosyukk/sweater , maybe somebody can help.

dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk15
VOLUME /main-app
ADD target/sweater-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
    links:
      - mysql_db:sweater_db
  mysql_db:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sweater_db
      MYSQL_USER: user228
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user228
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 13574637480326
```

application.properties:

```
#DB properties------------
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sweater_db?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user228
spring.datasource.password=user228
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#hibernate will automatically create, update, validate database tables
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
#generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#-------------------------

#Logs properties----------
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
#-------------------------

#Mail properties----------
spring.mail.host=smtp.yandex.ru
spring.mail.username=matveyandrosyuk2002@yandex.ru
spring.mail.password=rjpyptztrbbivjec
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
mail.debug=true
#-------------------------

#Captcha properties-------
recaptcha.secret=6LcXGhEgAAAAAFUMjaB1kpj4NHzBHyAnCXcMPVhW
#-------------------------

#Image path properties----
upload.path=D:/Projects/Intellij IDEA/Web Applications/Spring/sweater/uploads
#-------------------------

#Spring Session properties
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
#-------------------------

hostname=localhost:8080
```

Throws exception:

```
SQL State  : 08S01
Error Code : 0
Message    : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1243) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:121) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.setBeanFactory(JpaTransactionManager.java:333) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1826) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    ... 94 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: Communications link failure
```

Comment: [Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790923/docker-compose-spring-boot-postgres-connection) discusses the correct value for `spring.datasource.url` in a Docker context, and how to set it via an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links:

*Links allow you to define extra aliases by which a service is reachable from another service. They are not required to enable services to communicate*

However lets delete links and add hostname:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    hostname: api_service
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
  mysql_db:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    hostname: mysql_db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sweater_db
      MYSQL_USER: user228
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user228
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 13574637480326
```

The big problem is here: The "localhost" occurences in your application.properties refers to the api_service container localhost and not to your host machine localhost. So you can try:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/sweater_db?useSSL=false
```

you can also replace:

`hostname=localhost:8080` by `hostname=api_service:8080`

Since both services created in the docker compose are created in the same network, you could ping each one with its hostname.

try it and come back please

Comment: `links:` is an obsolete option and you should delete it entirely.  It doesn't make sense to include 0.0.0.0 ("listen on all interfaces") in `spring.datasource.url` but using the other container's Compose service name should work.

Comment: I also thought it was, but it is acutally deprecated only on docker cli not docker-compose, but I agree that we can / we should delete it here :) 
About the 0.0.0.0, I agree with you, I would rather replace it by an environment variable that contains the db hostname and use the hostname of the db, this way if i decide to migrate this to k8s for example i only change the environment variable w/o rebuilding the docker image :)

Comment: i can't run a container :  Cannot start service api_service: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Comment: Have you killed the previous containers ? docker-compose down ? And checked if any are running with docker ps?