# DOCKER_Cannot run multiple services by docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm set up docker compose for my project with 2 services: spring-boot and postgresql. I created Dockerfile and docker-compose,yml as below:

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
MAINTAINER linhan.com
COPY target/LinhAn-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar linhan-server-1.0.0.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/linhan-server-1.0.0.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'

services:
  spring_boot:
    image: 'linhan'
    build: .
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=123456
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
          
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
```

Then, when I type `docker-compose up` in terminal, postgres ran only, spring boot still not.

[image]

I searched google for solution but seems no hope. Please help me, thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: Your `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` is wrong, which may or may not be your issue; see for example [Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790923/docker-compose-spring-boot-postgres-connection).  The output of `docker-compose logs spring_boot` will probably be informative.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` to reference your service name instead of `localhost`. The service name is resolved automatically to your service since all services are part of the `default_network` by default in `docker-compose`.

```
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/test_db
```

Also, for clarity I would suggest you add the port to your `docker-compose` postgres service, so it is clear which port is being used, even if it is the default:

```
postgres:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
```

Also, another suggestion would be to try and use a `healthcheck` to see if your database service becomes available instead of a simple `depends_on`. The short version will mark the dependency fulfilled as soon as the container is `Running`, regardless of the availability of the database.

Either that, or you can add application logic to retry database connection in case of failure.