# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure (Docker, Spring Booot, Mac)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

Preconditions:

1. I am using Mac OS system, Apple M1 chip;
2. MySQL is installed using a docker image;
3. I am not using the docker-compose.yaml file;
4. My project is Spring Boot 2.x.

Detail:
I can use MySQL Workbench to connect to the database through 127.0.0.1:3306, and the application can also connect to the database through 127.0.0.1:3306. However, after using docker to package the image, the application cannot connect to the database through 127.0.0.1:3306 after starting the application in the container.

Comment: From the point of view of your Spring application container, 127.0.0.1 is that same container, not anywhere else.  Does the setup in [Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790923/docker-compose-spring-boot-postgres-connection) match your environment; or if not, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I don't want to use Docker Compose. Is there any other way?