# Spring Cloud Service cannot connect to Mysql Database in Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud

I have a problem about connecting mysql database to services in my Spring Cloud Project.
All these services are **user service**, **advertisement service** and lastly **report service**

Here is my error when I show logs of user service, advertisement service and lastly report service.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

How can I fix it?

Here is my docker-compose.yml shown below.

```
services:

  database:
    container_name: mysql-database
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3366:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      #MYSQL_DATABASE: "springbootuser"
      MYSQL_USER: "springmicroserviceuser"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "111111"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "111111"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "8181:8080"
    networks:
      - backend
    command:
      - start-dev

  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    container_name: "rmq3"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "rabbitmq"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "123456"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - backend

  configserver:
    image: configserver
    container_name: configServer
    build:
      context: ./configserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
    ports:
      - "9191:9191"
    networks:
      - backend

  eurekaserver:
    image: eurekaserver
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    build:
      context: ./discoveryserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
      WAIT_HOSTS: configserver:9191
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - backend


  gatewayserver:
    image: gatewayserver
    ports:
      - "8600:8600"
    build:
      context: ./api-gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      PROFILE: "default"
      SERVER_PORT: "8600"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      WAIT_HOSTS: configserver:9191
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
      eurekaserver:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - backend

  userservice:
    image: user-service
    build:
      context: ./user-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: "9000"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
      WAIT_HOSTS: configserver:9191
      DATABASE_HOST: database
      DATABASE_USER: springmicroserviceuser
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: 111111
      DATABASE_NAME: springbootuser
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
              "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
      }'
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - backend

  managementservice:
    image: management-service
    build:
      context: ./management-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: "9002"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
      WAIT_HOSTS: configserver:9191
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
      advertisementservice:
        condition: service_started
      reportservice:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "9002:9002"
    networks:
      - backend

  advertisementservice:
    image: advertisement-service
    build:
      context: ./advertisement-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: "9001"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
      WAIT_HOSTS: configserver:9191
      DATABASE_HOST: database
      DATABASE_USER: springmicroserviceuser
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: 111111
      DATABASE_NAME: springbootadvertisement
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
                  "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
      }'
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    networks:
      - backend


  reportservice:
    image: report-service
    build:
      context: ./report-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: "9003"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
      WAIT_HOSTS: configserver:9191
      DATABASE_HOST: database
      DATABASE_USER: springmicroserviceuser
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: 111111
      DATABASE_NAME: springbootreport
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
                      "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
      }'
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "9003:9003"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge


volumes:
  db-data:
```

Here is my project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices)

Here are all properties file of services under config server : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/tree/master/configserver/src/main/resources/configurations)

Comment: Which service(s) are having a problem; can you reduce the configuration to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the issue?  What is the `spring.datasource.url` property set to?  (See, for example, [Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790923/docker-compose-spring-boot-postgres-connection).)

Comment: @DavidMaze I already defined them( user service, advertisement service and report service) in post.

Comment: @DavidMaze I might find the conneciton refused issue. Is it possible to look through this link which I asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415922/spring-cloud-docker-config-server-cannot-fetch-properties-file-as-the-usage-of

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you look through my another question if you have any idea about it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73472367/spring-cloud-keycloak-javax-ws-rs-notauthorizedexception-http-401-unauthorized

Comment: @DavidMaze I couldn't fix the issue.