# Spring Cloud Docker - Config Server cannot fetch properties file as the usage of file backend

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud

I have a problem about getting all **properties** file from **config server** in my **Spring Cloud example**.

I've worked it with **Docker**.

I only fetched 4 properties file (**advertisement service, user service, api gateway and report service**) while other properties file(**eureka server and management service**) cannot be detected from config server.

Here is the **logs** of **config server**.

```
Adding property source: Config resource 'class path resource [configurations/user-servi
ce.properties]' via location 'classpath:/configurations/'
2022-08-19 11:03:52.912  INFO 1 --- [nio-9191-exec-2] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: Config resource 'class path resource [configurations/report-ser
vice.properties]' via location 'classpath:/configurations/'
2022-08-19 11:03:53.264  INFO 1 --- [nio-9191-exec-3] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: Config resource 'class path resource [configurations/advertisem
ent-service.properties]' via location 'classpath:/configurations/'
2022-08-19 11:03:56.223  INFO 1 --- [nio-9191-exec-4] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: Config resource 'class path resource [configurations/api-gatewa
y.properties]' via location 'classpath:/configurations/'
```

Here is **application.properties** of **management service**

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://configserver:9191/
spring.application.name=management-service
```

Here is the properties file for management service located under config server

```
server.port=9002

spring.application.name=management-service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka

keycloak.realm=master
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://keycloak:8181
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=spring-boot-microservice-keycloak
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.public-client=true

resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.management.registerHealthIndicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.management.event-consumer-buffer-size=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.management.slidingWindowType=COUNT_BASED
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.management.slidingWindowSize=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.management.wait-duration-in-open-state=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.management.permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state=3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.management.failure-rate-threshold=50

management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Here is **application.properties** of **eureka server**

```
spring.application.name=discovery-server
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://configserver:9191/
```

Here is the **properties** file for **eurekaserver** located under **config server**

```
spring.application.name=discovery-server
eureka.instance.hostname=eurekaserver
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/
server.port=8761
```

logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils=TRACE

Here is the **properties** file for eurekaserver

```
spring.application.name=discovery-server
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://configserver:9191/
```

Here is the **properties** file of **config server** : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/tree/master/configserver/src/main/resources/configurations)

```
spring.application.name=config-server
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=classpath:/configurations

server.port= 9191
```

I revised url like `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:///Users/sart/Desktop/SpringBootMicroservices/configserver/src/main/resources/configurations`
but nothing changed.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: How are you using those properties files?  The log output refers to `classpath:...` resources, are they being built into the jar files?  What's the specific problem you're running into, and do you need any particular container setup to reproduce it?

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?  Just these fragments of configuration doesn't seem like enough to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @qwercan - Do you have a stacktrace? or any error message? How did you know the properties are not fetched?

Comment: You didnt answer my question : `How did you know the properties are not fetched?`

Comment: Okay, Can you provide absolute path of all properties files (fetching and not fetching)

Comment: First, you need to see why there's no error / exception. Try to make an exception/error with the existing properties file (which is loading perfectly).