# Spring Cloud Docker Keycloak HTTP 401 Unauthorized error from API Gateway to Service

Tags: spring-boot, docker, keycloak, spring-cloud, api-gateway

I have a problem about creating user through Keycloak in my Spring Cloud example which runs on Docker.

When I make a request through this url `http://localhost:8600/api/v1/users/signup` (from api gateway to user service), I got this issue on the console.

Here is the error shown below.

```
2022-08-24 10:45:22.610  INFO 1 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] c.s.u.controller.UserController          : UserController | signUpUser is started
2022-08-24 10:45:22.610  INFO 1 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] c.s.u.controller.UserController          : UserController | signUpUser | SignUpRequest role : ROLE_USER
2022-08-24 10:45:22.610  INFO 1 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] c.s.u.controller.UserController          : UserController | signUpUser | SignUpRequest email : springbootmicroserviceuser@user.com
2022-08-24 10:45:22.611  INFO 1 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] c.s.u.controller.UserController          : UserController | signUpUser | SignUpRequest name : Micro User
2022-08-24 10:45:22.623  INFO 1 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] c.s.u.service.impl.UserServiceImpl       : UserServiceImpl | signUpUser is started
2022-08-24 10:45:22.627  INFO 1 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] c.s.u.service.impl.KeycloakServiceImpl   : KeycloakServiceImpl | createUserWithKeycloak is started
2022-08-24 10:45:22.763 ERROR 1 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw excepti
on [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized] with root cause

javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
```

Here is the keycloak configuration class defined in user service.

```
@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    public final static String serverUrl = "http://keycloak:8080";
    public final static String realm = "master";
    public final static String clientId = "spring-boot-microservice-keycloak";
    public final static String clientSecret = "ZDyqUYwec1qUeTdxiM2Ym99KiPE73vzU";
    final static String userName = "admin";
    final static String password = "admin";

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver(){
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public Keycloak keycloak(){
          return Keycloak.getInstance(serverUrl,
                realm,
                userName,
                password,
                clientId,
                clientSecret);
    }
}
```

Here is the keycloak part of docker-compose.yml

```
keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "8181:8080"
    networks:
      - backend
    command:
      - start-dev
```

Here is my project Link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices)

Comment: @F. Salvini I really need for your help

Comment: @dreamcrash I really need for your help.

Comment: @larsks I really need for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call on different port (8080) than Keycloak is exposed (8181). Try with changing serverUrl to "http://keycloak:8181".