# Can't get connected to mysql db using sequelize and docker

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I am Trying to connect to Mysql database using docker-compose in node.js

> ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.32.2:3306

here is how my `docker-compose.yml` looks like

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: 'mysql'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sweeft
      MYSQL_USER: sweeft_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345678

  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_USER: sweeft_user
      DB_PASSWORD: 12345678
      DB_NAME: sweeft
```

I am trying to connect like this

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('sweeft', 'sweeft_user', 12345678, {
  host: 'db',
  dialect: 'mysql',
});

export default sequelize;
```

error I am getting in Docker desktop

[image]

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790923/docker-compose-spring-boot-postgres-connection

Comment: in my code, I have already added "db" as host and in error, it shows that it is trying to connect to the correct port, which I have set in yml file. so I don't thing that's the problem