# Error creating docker-compose.yml + mysql

Tags: spring, docker

trying to solve the issue, check everything. Unfortunately. no results. If some had this kind of issur please help me. I use Spring Boot+Liquibase

docker compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  backend:
    image: 'stayhub-iso'
    container_name: 'self-generated-backend-container'
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
    environment: 
      - SERVER_PORT=9999
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=asdasd
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finalproject
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      - SPRING_JPA_SHOW_SQL=false
    ports:
      - 8004:9999

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: 'pg-container'
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=asdasd
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
```

APPLICATION.PROPERTIES

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finalproject
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
trying to make docker-compose up. But it stops and then i cant get accces to website

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5ZIY.png)

````
ecom.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
self-generated-backend-container  |
self-generated-backend-container  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
self-generated-backend-container  | 2023-11-25T07:38:20.876Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
self-generated-backend-container  | 2023-11-25T07:38:20.894Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
self-generated-backend-container  |
self-generated-backend-container  | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
self-generated-backend-container  | 2023-11-25T07:38:20.925Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
self-generated-backend-container  |
self-generated-backend-container  | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
self-generated-backend-container  |
self-generated-backend-container  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.7.jar!/:3.0.7]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.7.jar!/:3.0.7]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.7.jar!/:3.0.7]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.7.jar!/:3.0.7]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.7.jar!/:3.0.7]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.7.jar!/:3.0.7]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at bitlab.finalproject.StayHub.StayHubApplication.main(StayHubApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[myFinalProject.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[myFinalProject.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[myFinalProject.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[myFinalProject.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
self-generated-backend-container  | Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
self-generated-backend-container  |
self-generated-backend-container  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
self-generated-backend-container  |     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:285) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar!/:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.java:46) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.7.jar!/:3.0.7]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     ... 26 common frames omitted
self-generated-backend-container  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
self-generated-backend-container  |
self-generated-backend-container  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:175) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:280) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar!/:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     ... 29 common frames omitted
self-generated-backend-container  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
self-generated-backend-container  |
self-generated-backend-container  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:150) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:166) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:945) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     ... 36 common frames omitted
self-generated-backend-container  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
self-generated-backend-container  |     ... 39 common frames omitted
self-generated-backend-container  |
self-generated-backend-container exited with code 1```
````

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to contain the source code and diagnostics in plain text?

Comment: Communications link failure

```version: '3.1'

services:
  backend:
    image: 'stayhub-iso'
    container_name: 'booking-container'
    ports:
      - 8004:8080

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: 'mysqldb'
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: finalproject
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3308:3306```

Comment: ```server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finalproject
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

```

Comment: See [Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790923/docker-compose-spring-boot-postgres-connection) which describes the correct `spring.datasource.url` value.